# How to change the internal IP of Kubernetes worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I am trying to deploy a K8s cluster from scratch using Kelsey Hightower's Learn Kubernetes the Hard Way guide. In my case I am using Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Each of My Master and Workers have a DHCP network in eth0(10.0.2.x range) for pulling bits from the internet and a eth1 static range (10.10.10.x/24) for internal k8s communication.

```
 [vagrant@master-1 ~]$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION              CONTAINER-RUNTIME
worker-1   Ready    <none>   32s   v1.12.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.2.0-rc.0
worker-2   Ready    <none>   2s    v1.12.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.2.0-rc.0
```

I initially did not have the flags `-node-ip="10.10.10.x` and `-address="10.10.10.x"` setup.

Upon adding - I did remove the nodes and restart the kubelet service hopefully to register the nodes again however it seems to not want to update.

==
Following is a sample of the kubelet config:

```
/var/lib/kubelet/kubelet-config.yaml
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: "/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem"
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
clusterDomain: "cluster.local"
clusterDNS:
  - "10.32.0.10"
podCIDR: "${POD_CIDR}"
resolvConf: "/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
runtimeRequestTimeout: "15m"
tlsCertFile: "/var/lib/kubelet/${HOSTNAME}.pem"
tlsPrivateKeyFile: "/var/lib/kubelet/${HOSTNAME}-key.pem"
EOF


/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet
Documentation=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
After=containerd.service
Requires=containerd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kubelet \\
  --config=/var/lib/kubelet/kubelet-config.yaml \\
  --container-runtime=remote \\
  --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock \\
  --image-pull-progress-deadline=2m \\
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \\
  --network-plugin=cni \\
  --node-ip="$NODE_IP"
  --address="$NODE_IP"
  --register-node=true \\
  --v=2
```

and kube-api server:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver \\
  --advertise-address=${INTERNAL_IP} \\
  --allow-privileged=true \\
  --apiserver-count=3 \\
  --audit-log-maxage=30 \\
  --audit-log-maxbackup=3 \\
  --audit-log-maxsize=100 \\
  --audit-log-path=/var/log/audit.log \\
  --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC \\
  --bind-address=0.0.0.0 \\
  --client-ca-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem \\
  --enable-admission-plugins=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,NodeRestriction,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota \\
  --enable-swagger-ui=true \\
  --etcd-cafile=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem \\
  --etcd-certfile=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \\
  --etcd-keyfile=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --etcd-servers=https://10.10.10.11:2379,https://10.10.10.12:2379 \\
  --event-ttl=1h \\
  --experimental-encryption-provider-config=/var/lib/kubernetes/encryption-config.yaml \\
  --kubelet-certificate-authority=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem \\
  --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \\
  --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --kubelet-https=true \\
  --runtime-config=api/all \\
  --service-account-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/service-account.pem \\
  --service-cluster-ip-range=10.32.0.0/24 \\
  --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 \\
  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \\
  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --v=2
```

Also in vagrant I believe eth0 is the NAT device as I see the `10.0.2.15` ip assigned to all vms (master/slaves)

```
[vagrant@worker-1 ~]$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:75:dc:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 84633sec preferred_lft 84633sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe75:dc3d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:24:a4:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.206/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth1
       valid_lft 3600sec preferred_lft 3600sec
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:76:22:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.21/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe76:224a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[vagrant@worker-1 ~]$
```

I guess the ask is how to update the internal-ip and external-ip post changes to the kubelet configuration

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/) which explains how to proceed with Kubelet  adjustments on a live cluster?

Comment: @mk_sta - thanks! i ll give this a try..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I edited `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` - adding the `--node-ip flag` to `KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS` and restarted kubelet with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

And **kubectl get nodes -o wide** reported the new IP addresses immediately.  It took a bit longer when I did it on the master - but it happened eventually.

Comment: You probably mean `kubectl get nodes -o wide`, not `kubeadm get nodes -o wide`.

Comment: Yes, thank you Günther Eberl - answer edited to reflect the correct command.

Comment: I did do this on worker node but it's not changing. hmmm

Comment: @Michael: IMO `--node-ip ` should be set in `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` and not in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` - see here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#workflow-when-using-kubeadm-init

Comment: @Dieshe - We're all learning, hopefully - thanks for the info, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 10):

What I did is similar to the answer from Michael, only I didn't edit `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` .

As suggested [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/) it is stated (I emphasize some points)

> The file that **can** contain **user-specified** flag overrides with `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS` is sourced from `/etc/default/kubelet` (for DEBs), or `/etc/sysconfig/kubelet` (for RPMs). `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS` is last in the flag chain and has the highest priority in the event of conflicting settings

So rather than changing files that are meant to be automatically changed (maybe due to upgrades or the like) I changed `/etc/sysconfig/kubelet` with `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS='--node-ip 10.0.0.3'` (the options that one can use can be seen with `kubelet --help`).

Then I did, as specified by other answers:

```
systemctl daemon-reload #actually not needed as per commentary below.
systemctl restart kubelet
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

And the internal Ip was changed accordingly.

Comment: This worked for me. And i think it is the right way to do it. thanks

Comment: No need for the `systemctl daemon-reload` as you're not changing any of the unit files.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions not working for me, i had to add --node-ip directly to Exec start on each worker nodes

vim /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

**add node ip flag**

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --node-ip=10.0.0.11
```

then kubectl get node return the node Internal IPs

Comment: Isn't this what the accepted answer is suggesting?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin the difference is the location of the flag --node-ip suggested answer is to put it in KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS which is didn't work with me, however putting it directly in ExecStart does work

Comment: Putting it directly in the service file has the risk, that this file might be overwritten when upgrading the package.

Comment: i haven't tried the upgrade yet, i which upgrade will remove the old IP that's not used and replace it with the new one i don't know if that's possible,

Answer (score 0):

For new clusters that are initialized using `kubeadm`, the approach I am showing below is recommended way, as stated in the file /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf:

> Preferably, the user should use the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead.

The cluster has to initialized using this command

```
kubeadm init --config=/tmp/kubeadm-init-config.yaml
```

with this config file /tmp/kubeadm-init-config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    ########## NOTICE THIS ########## < < < < < < < < < <
    node-ip: {{ internal_ip_address }}
patches:
  directory: /tmp/kubelet-patches
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
clusterName: {{ domain_name }}
controlPlaneEndpoint: {{ control_plane_endpoint }}
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: {{ pod_network_cidr }}
```

The same approach can be followed for Join, but with JoinConfiguration, though it is significantly more complex because of the need to generate the token and the CA hash manually.