# How can I change the Internal IP of my Kubernetes node?

Tags: kubernetes, ip, kubelet

My kubelet has an internal IP that points to eth0.  How can I change it to eth1?

I have already tried editing `KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`  both with and without `--node-ip` flag as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942488/how-to-change-the-internal-ip-of-kubernetes-worker-nodes).

In both cases, the internal ip reflects eth0

Comment: What are your current configs and how did you bootstrap your cluster? More importantly, what exactly do you want to achieve? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: My goal is simply to get a working cluster.  I am working with Calico and have tried many different starting points (still learning the capabilities of the system). This particular question pertains to the Self-managed on prem installation (https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/). After installation, my worker nodes are functioning as expected, but my master is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I was misusing the --node-ip flag in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

It will not autodetect or point. You need to manually specify the IP address on each node.  Then rebuild.  Fixed!