# How to set/change internal ip of a node in kuberenetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, ip

I would like to know how internal-ip of the node in a kubernetes cluster is set. When I see in my environment it is taking its network ip as internal-ip. What if the IP address changes if the same node is reconnected from a different network. I also want to know how to set that internal ip of a node to 127.0.0.1 for running the cluster on the standalone server which will help to ship the entire cluster as ova image. Does my question makes sense? I would like know your opinions on this

Comment: Did you take a look: https://medium.com/@kanrangsan/how-to-specify-internal-ip-for-kubernetes-worker-node-24790b2884fd  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942488/how-to-change-the-internal-ip-of-kubernetes-worker-nodes ?

Comment: Thanks @Malgorzata I went through the blog but for my use case. I want my node-ip to be 127.0.0.1, I added this parameter and restarted the service. But the IP is not getting updateed, still the old IP persists. Is it not permissible to have node-ip as 127.0.0.1 or something else? Can you throw some light on this

Comment: Yes it is possible to have node ip 127.0.0.1, for example master. Can you provide more information about your setup, cloud provider etc?  How do you install Kubernetes ?